# Espresso access view id

Tags: android, automated-tests

we build an App where the most view's are created programmatically. Now I like to build some Espresso GUI test's. To find and access this view I like to set the view ID (view.setId( Unique Number)).

In my Espresso Test :

`UiObject appViews = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().**resourceId**(id))`

I am only able to access Real Android Resource ID (not set with setId() ).

Is there a way to get find objects with programmatically view ID ?

the usage of the view setContentDescription is also not a solution, because this is used for Accessible :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html 
and not for GUI Testing !

Regards
Stephan

Comment: You can use `onView(withId(R.id.view_id))` to access a view using Espresso

Comment: Are you sure it works with programmatically  generated id. The withId try to find the description by idDescription = resources.getResourceName(id);

Comment: You're right. What you can do is try to use some Hamcrest function such as `withChild()`. Something like `onView(withId(R.id.parent_container)).check(matches(withChild(...));`

Comment: This also use resource id.